# How to get usersinfo after keycloak login

Tags: php, keycloak

I am integrating Keycloak SSO with my php application.

This is what i am doing, if the user is not logged in i redirect to keycloak login page:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/LearnKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=demo-php&response_type=code&redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fkeycloak-php%2Findex.php
```

After successful login i am able to get two request parameters from the redirected page named: session_state and code.

How can i use these to get the users information from keycloak.

Comment: You need to exchange that code for the token first. Check documentation about authorization code flow of Open ID Connect spec.

Comment: Thanks Jan, already done and working thanks.